# VBA to open MyComputer at a specific folder

Tags: ms-access, vba

Ive just inherited an MS Access 2003 system and need a bit of VBA to put behind a command button to open MyComputer at a specific folder to view the files there.
The folder name will come from a field on a form.
I did have

Application.FollowHyperLink "C:\" & Me![ref]    (ref is in the format abcd-1234)

when its hard-coded it works fine, but i cant seem to get it to open when picking the foldername up from the form.

any hints? (other than binning access!)
thanks

Answer (score 1):

See what the text looks like as you're submitting it to FollowHyperlink.  You can insert a line like this in your code:

```
MsgBox "C:\" & Me![ref]
```

Perhaps it's not what you expect.  It's always good to check.

What happens when it doesn't work.  Do you see any error messages or any other symptoms which could help us nail this down?

My first thought was spaces in a folder name might create problems.  But I don't think that's the answer because FollowHyperlink works fine for me in this example:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink "C:\Access\spaces in name\"
```

So the best I can offer is to see what you're asking FollowHyperlink to use.  If that effort doesn't lead you to the answer, add a specific example which fails to your question.

Comment: My first guess was that the argument needed to be wrapped in quotes, e.g., Chr(34) & "C:\" & Me![ref] & Chr(34).

Answer (score 1):

This code always work for me:

```
Dim filePath = <"Insert the path of the directory to open inside of opening and closing parenthesis">

Application.FollowHyperlink filePath, vbNormalFocus
```

Normally, I store a few directories in a table inside the DBMS, which helps when linking hundreds of images to a database instead of embedding.  For instance, I have a table called, "dbLocations."  Inside this table, there are only two fields: 1) picLocation 2) Description.

The field picLocation has the value of the network path, i.e, C:\My Documents or G:\Whatever Directory or \\groups1\for UNC paths.

The field Description is what it implies, a description of the picLocation.

I use tables to store directory locations because they linking to files (.jpg, .png) stored on a network drive.  As time evolves, directories can get changed (I move a folder to another location, or if the UNC changes, etc.).

If you hard code the location(s) over several subs or modules, you will need to change each one; which is very inefficient.  So, in order to save time and a lot of headaches, I use the Domain Lookup function which allows me to only change the file location just once and in an easy to find place, namely, the dbLocations table.

In essence, I am looking up the value of the location inside the table where the picLocation matches the description of, Alert Pics.  (I am creating a database that will be used to track Trespassers and other vagrant persons for work)

```
Dim filePath as String

filePath = DLookup("picLocation", "dbLocations", "[Description] = 'Alert Pics'")
Application.FollowHyperlink filePath, vbNormalFocus
```

With these three lines of simple code, you can navigate to a specific directory.